# Jersey: combine multiple path params into one

Tags: java, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I annotated my resource with the following path.

```
@Path("/hello/world/{param}/{sub-resources}")
```

which should handle requests like this:

```
/hello/world/one/blah
/hello/world/two/blah/blah/blah
/hello/world/three/a/million/other/sub-resources
```

I need to extract {param} and everything that goes after it but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JAX-RS, a simple path parameter like `/hello/world/{param}` will by default use the regular expression of `[^/]+`, which matches only the current path segment.

You can customise this by specifying a more permissive regex for the parameter that includes slashes. For example, this will match all of the URLs under `/hello/world`, with any number of child path segments:

```
@Path("/hello/world/{param:.+})
```

Or if you wanted to push the top level segment into a separate variable, you could do:

```
@Path("/hello/world/{param}/{sub-resources:.+}
```